# Python paramiko: custom paramiko.log file name

Tags: python, jenkins, paramiko

I am having problem with paramiko.log, 
it is causing  IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/tmp/paramiko.log'
As there are more Python commands using it for logging at same time. 
Is there a way of a custom creation of the paramiko.log name each time? meaning paramiko_03_03_2014_16-00.log or paramiko1.log,
hoping this will solve conflicts when Jenkins jobs are run using same Python commands.

Thank you any help you can give me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `strftime()` function to name the file, using the `datetime` module to retrieve it e.g.

```
now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d--%H-%M-%S')

filename = 'paramiko_'+now+'.log'
log = open(filename)
```

this will make a file named `paramiko_2014-03-04--16-05-00.log`
where the time is replaced by the time retrieved by `datetime.datetime.now()`

Comment: Thank you, how do I get paramiko to use it as log file and not use the default? and the Jenkins job needs to know about it so I can remove it when the job finishes.